# MySQL homework, joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble finishing my last problem on my hw. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Query 4:
Write and run an SQL statement that displays number of customers and average balance of customers by area code in descending order of average balance.

```
SELECT 
SELECT CUS_AREACODE AS "Area Code", COUNT(CUS_CODE) "# of Customers", ROUND(AVG(CUS_BALANCE),2) "Average Balance",
FROM CUSTOMER
ORDER BY CUS_BALANCE DESC;
```

There's a second table CUSTOMER_2 and I'm not sure how to join the thing. Code isn't working anymore. I kept messing around with trying to join and now its telling me I'm missing an expression for FROM.  TIA

```
Columns for tables
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  CUS_CODE  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  CUS_LNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  CUS_FNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  CUS_INITIAL   CHAR(1),
  CUS_AREACODE  CHAR(3) DEFAULT '615' NOT NULL CHECK(CUS_AREACODE IN ('615','713','931')),
  CUS_PHONE CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  CUS_BALANCE   NUMBER(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  CONSTRAINT CUS_UI1 UNIQUE(CUS_LNAME,CUS_FNAME));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_2 (
  CUS_CODE  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  CUS_LNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  CUS_FNAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  CUS_INITIAL   CHAR(1),
  CUS_AREACODE  CHAR(3),
  CUS_PHONE CHAR(8));
```

As suggested I believe I'm supposed to do a union but I'm not sure how to code after I've create the Union

```
SELECT CUS_CODE, CUS_AREACODE 
FROM CUSTOMER
UNION ALL
SELECT CUS_CODE, CUS_AREACODE
FROM CUSTOMER_2
```

I'm pretty much stuck after that. Do I need to turn the union into a new table and then use my original code?

Comment: What column joins the two tables? Is there a customer_id column on each table? Posting the columns of the tables would be great. Otherwise we have no idea what is in each table.

Comment: I think its CUS_CODE for both tables

Comment: What's the diff in both the tables and why do you want to join it? From the current table definition I see that the column CUS_BALANCE is not present in CUSTOMER_2 table. If there are some records in CUTOMER and some in CUSTOMER_2 but different customers then you can use UNION to club all the records in a subquery then perform he AVG and COUNT on it.

Comment: Yeah I just figured I needed to do a union right now. (more cus_code and area codes in customer_2 table). The only thing is I'm not sure what to code after I do a union for the two tables. Especially where to code in the AVG.

Comment: Um, this isn't MySQL. And why is there a second customer table?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the union of both the tables (note that the column count and order should be same), then use that as sub-query and then take the count/avg as required. Note that I've added CUS_BALANCE from table 2 since we want that for average, check and modify according to your data.

```
SELECT sq.CUS_AREACODE AS "Area Code"
     , COUNT(sq.CUS_CODE) "# of Customers"
     , ROUND(AVG(sq.CUS_BALANCE),2) "Average Balance"
  FROM (SELECT CUS_CODE
             , CUS_AREACODE
             , CUS_BALANCE 
          FROM CUSTOMER
         UNION ALL
        SELECT CUS_CODE
             , CUS_AREACODE
             , CUS_BALANCE
          FROM CUSTOMER_2) as sq --alias to the subquery
 GROUP BY sq.CUS_AREACODE  --required for aggregate functions         
 ORDER BY sq.CUS_AREACODE
        , sq.CUS_BALANCE DESC;
```

**Note1:** Since you are using aggregate functions count/avg you will have to use `GROUP BY` clause too, else it will result in error.